# Python script not sending linux commands. i used Paramiko for remote SSH connection

Tags: linux, ssh, paramiko, python-3.6

```
import paramiko
import time
import os


ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('server',port=22,username='user',password='pass123')
print("connected to the linux machine from windows machine.")

channel=ssh.invoke_shell()

channel_data = str()

while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        channel_data += channel.recv(9999).decode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')
        os.system('cls')
        print("##### Device Output #####")
        print("\n",channel_data)
        print("\n #####################")
    else:
        continue

    time.sleep(5)

    if channel_data.endswith('[root@home ~]#'):
        #if block statements are not executed why
        print("Hi,why not executing this statement")
        ssh.send('cd /\n')
        #stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('pwd')
        #output1=stdout.readlines()
        print("My present working directory is")
    elif channel_data.endswith('[root@home /]#'):
        #Also elif block statements are not executed why
        ssh.send('mkdir BB444')
        #stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('mkdir /pn444')
        #output1=stdout.readlines()
        print("created pn444 directory")
```

I am using paramiko for ssh connection. I am able to login to linux machine. then i am checking the condition i.e if channel_data.endswith('[root@home ~]#') then send "cd /" command else if channel_data.endswith('[root@home /]#') then send 'mkdir BB444' command but this script is not sending these commands. after debugging i see that these sending command statements are not executed. Please let me know what mistake i am making here.

I am using python 3.6, paramiko 2.1.1

Comment: Usually the prompt ends in a space.  Maybe `endswith('[root@home /]# ')` ? Or `'[root@home ~]# '`.

Comment: Thanks Girisha. Your suggestion solved the issue.

Comment: Hi Girisha, I faced similar issue in other case. During command interaction, when output comes with string 'Would you like to configure Network now? (yes/no) [default yes] ', script need to send 'yes' command. Below is the code written for this. channel.send('yes\n') is not executing.                                                                                             elif channel_data.endswith('Would you like to configure Prime Network now? (yes/no) [default yes] '):
        channel.send('yes\n')

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be the python script. i encountered similar problems while sending remote commands to putty ssh connection from a python script. If you are in a corporate network. some administrators strip the commands from the parameters like -m which i use for putty. so you can login but when you try to send a remote command. it does not reach the server. Check with your administrator if you are on a corporate network about remote commands for ssh connections.

Comment: Thanks Sivaprasath. Actually Linux servers on corporate network only. I will check with administrator regarding your suggestion but currently i am sending very simple commands like "cd /" or "pwd" or "mkdir pn444"

Comment: you are sending remote commands which is security issue.so no commands goes through. One more thing if you are working with CISCO servers or Routers then its an inbuilt security to strip remote commands off ssh connection commands.

Comment: I am able to create a folder from the script. it means I am able to send the commands successfully from  script. Below is the code.            import paramiko

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('server',port=22,username='user',password='pass123')
print("connected to the linux machine from windows machine. Okay basu")
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('mkdir BB444')
output1=stdout.readlines()
print('created a new directory is',output1)

Comment: if only first command gets executed, then it might be because your remote command takes only one command. few other ssh programs support multiline remote commands. but most of them just executes the first command and exits the environment. before the next command can be passed. check the remote command attribute of paramiko once again. whether it can support multiline remote commands